# Possible causes of glbadcontext

Tags: opengl, runtime-error

What are the possible causes of glbadcontext ?

Can it be related to OpenGL version , GPU , mesa libraries ( in linux) , memory corruption or something else?

I'm not experienced in OpenGL and I want to develop a clear understanding of that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "bad context" error in OpenGL. There is the `GL_CONTEXT_LOST` error. What's this error about?

One of the consequences of programmability is that people can write *bad* programs with programmable hardware. So as GPUs have become more programmable, they now become susceptible to issues that arise when a GPU program does something stupid. In a modern OS, when a CPU process does something wrong, the OS kills the process. In a modern OS, when a GPU "process" starts doing the wrong thing (accessing memory it's not allowed to, infinite loops, other brokenness), the OS resets the GPU.

The difference is that a GPU reset, depending on the reason for it and the particular hardware, often affects *all* programs using the GPU, not just the one that did a bad thing. OpenGL reports such a scenario by declaring that the OpenGL context has been lost.

The function `glGetGraphicsResetStatus` can be used to query the party responsible for a GPU reset. But even that is a half-measure, because all it tells you is whether it was your context or someone else's that caused the reset. And there's no guarantee that it will tell you *that*, since `glGetGraphicsResetStatus` can return `GL_UNKNOWN_CONTEXT_RESET`, which represents not being able to determine who was at fault.

Ultimately, a GPU reset could happen for any number of reasons. Outside of making sure your code doesn't do something that causes one, all you can do is accept that they can happen and deal with them when they do.

Comment: What is exactly the GPU reset? Power outage ? Memory corruption ? and how to deal with that ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi: Information added to post.